# Setting up ngx-graphs, TouchEvent error

Tags: angular, d3.js, ngx-graph

Trying to set https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-graph but I am not sure what the peer decencies for d3 need to be.  When rendering, I get an error:

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: TouchEvent

But no other information what it's missing.  Any other tips here?

Comment: any one resolved this?

Comment: This should be fixed in version 6.